# The existence of a Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing

According to the theory, in order to have a Fourier transform of a function, the latter must have finite energy. Nevertheless, the Dirac impulse has infinite energy, but its Fourier transform exists. How is that possible?

Comment: It's not a function. The real answer is that there are several different Fourier transforms and they are defined on different spaces of functions / distributions.

Comment: The $\delta$ *function* can also be consider as a (finite) measure where Fourier transforms are all defined.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Fourier_transform_on_function_spaces) for how we can define Fourier transforms on different spaces, starting from $L^1$, then $L^2$ and tempered distributions.